# Segmentation fault after Mongodb-c-driver work

Tags: c, linux, mongodb, memory-leaks, valgrind

My Mongodb-c-driver program working well, without errors at the compiling and run time, but when I check the program with Valgrind I have memory leak.

```
==30532==    at 0x4C29DB4: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==30532==    by 0x506BCA5: bson_malloc0 (in /usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0)

==30532==    by 0x4E3B0CB: mongoc_client_new (in /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0)

==30532==    by 0x4009BA: main (ranker.c:28)

==30532== LEAK SUMMARY:

==30532==    definitely lost: 6,656 bytes in 1 blocks

==30532==    indirectly lost: 2,598 bytes in 11 blocks

==30532==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==30532==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==30532==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==30532== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==30532== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

The Valgrind notes the line with:

```
client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
```

In the last lines in program I have:

```
mongoc_client_destroy (client);
```

What is that and what can I do in order to avoid LEAK SUMMARY?

Edit: I still have some issues during work with MongoDB, is there anyone out there who knows how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the **mongoc_cleanup()** routine at the end of **main()**? The MongoDB C driver has some internal state that is initialized during startup (especially for SSL). It needs to be released manually by calling the cleanup function at the end of your program.

Here is an example: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/b2b5c6e8ebdcbf8593292ae8efcb91b94aa23995/examples/example-client.c#L72

Hope that helps,

-- Christian

Comment: yes I call a mongoc_cleanup() it does not help, thank you anyway